# AAD version for botframework authentication in Teams

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, botframework, microsoft-teams

I'm trying to add authentication (and SSO) to my Virtual Assistant (+Skills) bot for Teams.

In this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/authentication/add-authentication?tabs=dotnet%2Cdotnet-sample) they are using "Azure Active Directory" while creating the OAuth Connection.
So AAD v1 instead of v2, as used in other tutorials [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-authentication-sso?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp%2Ceml) and [here](https://microsoft.github.io/botframework-solutions/overview/whats-new/1.0/enable-sso-with-skills-using-oauthcredentials-setting/).

Is there a reason for that?
Is it related to Teams?
Is v2 not supported by Teams?

Comment: Not sure why you are asking "Is v2 not supported by Teams?". Based on [this part](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-authentication-sso?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp%2Ceml#about-the-samples), "Currently, only the Azure AD v2 identity provider is supported." AAD Authentication should support both AAD v1 and v2. But SSO should only support v2.

Comment: The sentence you are reporting is referred to "bot-sso" scenario: only v2 supported.
My question is "why they use v1 in the "Teams-bot" sample?". If the answer to this question is "because v2 is not supported by Teams", I should conclude that the scenario "Teams-bot-sso" is not supported. Is it correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just saw that on Friday (09/18/2020) Microsoft updated the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/authentication/add-authentication?tabs=dotnet%2Cdotnet-sample). It now contains both AAD v1 and AAD v2 versions.